# Transit visa obtainable at Zurich Airport

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, zrh

We are 2 South Africans going on a cruise in Croatia and have an 14 hour layover at Zurich.  I have been advised that we can apply for a transit visa at the airport in Zurich.  Is this easy to obtain?

Comment: What sort of visa do you have for Croatia? (It might already cover you, as Croatia is set to join Schengen in a few years time)

Comment: None of these two alleged duplicates are really related to this question.

Comment: Are you asking if you need a visa to change airplane in Zurich or to leave the airport during your 14 hour layover?

Comment: You can't generally apply for a transit visa *at* the airport. If you need one (which is not the case here), it should be obtained beforehand.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo IMHO is really a dupe - travelling from non-schengen to non-schengen country via Zurich.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this document](https://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/dam/data/bfm/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-d.pdf), you do not need a transit visa. This is because you stay in the transit zone (Croatia is not a Schengen member) and as a South-African you do not feature on the list of countries which need a transit visa:

> - Afghanistan
> - Kamerun
> - Äthiopien
> - Kongo (dem. Republik)
> - Bangladesch
> - Nigeria
> - Eritrea
> - Pakistan
> - Ghana
> - Somalia
> - Irak
> - Sri Lanka
> - Iran
> - Syrien
> - Türkei